# Getting values from two groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a 500 line query, which I'll try and summarize in a simple query:

```
SELECT 
   max(t.USER_ID)
  ,max(t.OFFICE_ID)
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN t.VALUE > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  /COUNT(t.VALUE) as Value_Avg

FROM(
   SELECT
     p.USER_ID
    ,c.OFFICE_ID
    ,h.VALUE
    , ... etc (Join, Where, ...)
   ) t
GROUP BY t.USER_ID
```

A query like that would give the following results:

```
USER_ID   OFFICE_ID   Value_Avg
1001      100         0.8
1002      100         0.75
1010      200         0.50
```

Basically showing the percentage of values greater than 10 by user.

Now, assuming User 1001 had 20 logs and user 1002 had 10 logs, and I wanted to also have a 4th column to average by department, how would I go ahead and do that if I could only use one group by?

Comment: I do hope you're using `SUM` and not `COUNT` in the original query. `COUNT` will count all values, so feeding it `1` or `0` makes no difference.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My bad @JeroenMostert, yes sum .. I've used count when placing NULL after ELSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need calculate the Department average in a separated query. And then join with your current query to add the department average

```
WITH dept as (
   SELECT t.OFFICE_ID,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN t.VALUE > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        / COUNT(t.VALUE) as dept_Avg
   FROM ( ... ) t
   GROUP BY t.OFFICE_ID
)
SELECT 
    max(t.USER_ID)
  , max(t.OFFICE_ID)
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN t.VALUE > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   / COUNT(t.VALUE) as Value_Avg    
  , MAX( d.dept_Avg ) as dept_Avg
FROM ( ... ) t
JOIN dept d
  ON t.OFFICE_ID = d.OFFICE_ID
GROUP BY t.USER_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT p.USER_ID, c.OFFICE_ID,
       AVG(CASE WHEN t.Value > 10 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as value_avg
FROM . . .
GROUP BY p.USER_ID, c.OFFICE_ID;
```

You don't need a subquery.  This assumes that `Value` is never `NULL`.  If it is, then change the expression to:

```
       AVG(CASE WHEN t.Value > 10 THEN 1.0
                WHEN t.Value IS NOT NULL THEN 0
           END) as value_avg
```

Comment: Not sure if that is what OP want. But I think you need change the field order very unlike it one user had more than one department`GROUP BY c.OFFICE_ID; p.USER_ID,`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . This is based on the OP's desired results.  I cannot speak for the data model, which is not explained.